# How can I wrap a method with optional parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, default-value, optional-parameters

I have the following C# class (simplified here):

```
internal static class Assertions {
    public static void Assert(bool condition, string message = "Assertion failed") {
        if (!condition) { throw new System.Exception(message); }
    }

    public static void NotNull(object o, string message = "Assertion failed") {
        Assert(!Object.ReferenceEquals(o, null), message);
    }

    public static void EtCaetera(..., string message = "Assertion failed") {
        Assert(..., message);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a method `Assertions.Assert()` with an optional parameter `string message = "Assertion failed"`.

When I write a wrapper around that method, I'd like the wrapper to have a default parameter `string message`, but I'd like to avoid repeating the default value (`"Assertion failed"`) because that violates the DRY principle: if I want to change the message `"Assertion failed"` to `"I crashed"`, I'll have to change that default value in many places.

How can I pass-through the "missingness" of the optional parameter? I'm looking for something like:

```
public static void NotNull(object o, string message = Type.Missing) {
    Assert(!Object.ReferenceEquals(o, null), message);
}
```

ANother option would be not to use optional parameters and provide two versions of each method, but that would quickly get cumbersome.

Comment: A `const` string perhaps... ?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead That's a great idea, I don't know why I hadn't thought about that.

Answer (score 3):

Optional parameters are resolved at compile time and they're not replaced for *special* values so you don't have many options here.

My suggestion, if you don't want to repeat yourself, is to introduce a special value (to mimic what `Type.Missing` is):

```
internal static class Assertions {
    public static void Assert(bool condition, string message = null) {
        if (!condition) {
            throw new System.Exception(message ?? "Assertion failed");
        }
    }
}

internal static class Wrapper {
    public static void Assert(bool condition, string message = null) {
        Assertions.Assert(condition, message);
    }
}
```

This has another (IMO big) advantage: if you **change your error message** (or you'll **localize it**) you won't have to change all your code (and existing compiled libraries will be ***updated***). Don't forget  that, in your original code, a call like this:

```
Assertions.Assert(value > 0);
```

Will be translated (and compiled, even if you use a `const` field) to:

```
Assertions.Assert(value > 0, "Assertion failed");
```

So, even if you'll change your default message, compiled assemblies won't get updated.

Comment: Note that you could simplify this using the coalesce (`??`) operator, ie. `message ?? "Assertion failed"`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `null` as the default value for optional arguments.

```
internal static class Assertions {
    private const string DefaultMessage = "Assertion failed";

    public static void Assert(bool condition, string message = null) {
        message = message ?? DefaultMessage;
        if (!condition) { throw new System.Exception(message); }
    }

    public static void NotNull(object o, string message = null) {
        message = message ?? DefaultMessage;
        Assert(!Object.ReferenceEquals(o, null), message);
    }

    public static void EtCaetera(..., string message = null) {
        message = message ?? DefaultMessage;
        Assert(..., message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value needs to be specified on the first method called (i.e. your wrapper) as this is where the value is applied to the parameter. `Type.Missing` is a special value that has meaning in COM interop. Here are some options you could try that may suit your needs.

1. Use the [OptionalAttibute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.optionalattribute.aspx) on the base method and specify the default value on the overridden method.

   ```
   class Class2 : Class1
   {
       public override string MethodWithOptParams(string message = "default message")
       {
           return base.MethodWithOptParams(message);
       }
   }

   class Class1
   {
       public virtual string MethodWithOptParams([Optional]string message)
       {
           return message;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Declare your default values as constants in and apply the same constant as the default value.

   ```
   class Class2 : Class1
   {
       public override string MethodWithOptParams(string message = DefaultMessage)
       {
           return base.MethodWithOptParams(message);
       }
   }

   class Class1
   {
       protected const string DefaultMessage = "default message";

       public virtual string MethodWithOptParams(string message = DefaultMessage)
       {
           return message;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use null as the default value in your wrapper and code the two alternative calls to the base method.

   ```
   class Class2 : Class1
   {
       public override string MethodWithOptParams(string message = null)
       {
           if (message == null)
           {
               return base.MethodWithOptParams();
           }
           else
           {
               return base.MethodWithOptParams(message);
           }
       }
   }

   class Class1
   {
       public virtual string MethodWithOptParams(string message = "default message")
       {
           return message;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: how OptionalAttribute will change **C#** behavior? Here it's pretty useless. 3rd method is same as do it in _inner_ class (just more prolix). 2nd one is good, I wouldn't do it for strings because of localization but it works.

Comment: The `OptionalAttribute` just allows you to specify an optional parameter without having to specify a default value. It's functionally equivalent to `Type parameter = default(Type)`.

Comment: You're quite right that using default strings is often a bad idea due to localization, unless it's a lookup value into a resource file.

Comment: About [Optional], yes that's why in that example I think it's useless! I agree for 2nd comment (even if...honestly...I dislike localized exception messages too because most of time it's only information you get from customers...)

Comment: +1 for method 2. Method 1 is not applicable in my case, since I have many wrappers around a single core method, so using I would still need to provide the default value for each wrapper, and besides, the core method can be called without a wrapper, so it should have the correct default value anyway. Also, why did you separate the wrapper in subclasses ? In my question, the core method and wrappers are just static methods and there is no inheritance involved.